# United States residents can't preach in Canada?

Tags: united-states, canada, immigration, religion, religious-law

I have recently been told by someone with a background working in American border patrol that if an American tells a Canadian border patrol agent they're crossing to *worship*, things will be fine; but if the American says they're crossing to *preach*, there will be issues, even if they are volunteering without pay. I think he said the reason had to do with taking the slot/job from someone else who could have filled the role in Canada.

Is it true that a United States resident is restricted from crossing the border to preach in Canada, even if they are not a full-time evangelist and volunteering without pay? If so, can such individuals do anything to gain permission, maybe getting a permit, perhaps?

Comment: Would you be getting paid or not?

Comment: I imagine that Canadian rights protections allow foreigners to enter and set up a soapbox in the local park.  Preaching _in a religious service_ where the preacher is normally a professional member of the clergy employed by the congregation or religious institution is another matter (potentially, @MichaelHall, even if the preacher is not being paid).

Comment: There is a [Religious work visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/foreign-workers/work-without-permit/authorization-work-without-work-permit-clergy.html).

Comment: @phoog, Potentially.  But paid "work" is treated quite differently than volunteering to help, and is certain to affect the answer.

Comment: I've edited the answer for clarification. I'm primarily interested in people who volunteer to preach without pay and are not full-time evangelists. (However, if being a full-time evangelist affects the answer in any way, I'd also like to know about that.)

Comment: Would "preaching" be any different than being invited to be guest speaker at a commencement ceremony?  Or to lead a discussion on the positive effects of exercise?  In other words, do you have reason to believe that the topic of faith or religious belief is treated differently under the law?

Comment: @MichaelHall Not necessarily. I was told this claim in the context of preaching, but I'm unsure whether it's about preaching in particular or about giving speeches in general.

Comment: FWIW, there are similar examples in U.S. immigration law, both with clergy and with reporters.

Comment: @MichaelHall in US immigration law, volunteering to do something that is normally paid is just as forbidden as working. (As I understand it, this to prevent abuses such as bringing in foreign workers who claim to be volunteering and then paying them under the table or otherwise subjecting them to illegal conditions.) I suppose Canada is similarly wise to such practices and therefore bases their labor protections on the effect on the local labor market rather than on the benefit accruing to the foreign visitor.  That is certainly consistent with their permissive approach to remote working.

Comment: @phoog, can you cite a law showing it is "just as forbidden"?

Comment: @phoog What if the volunteered speaking (whether preaching, lecturing, etc.) is normally _unpaid_? Say, for example, a small congregation where the person who normally speaks isn't paid.

Comment: If this question is specifically about Canadian laws around religious freedoms perhaps you should clarify.  Otherwise i would interpret the customs agent's casual remark as a generic warning about needing a work visa to perform work for pay.  Phoog's last remark notwithstanding, I don't think there are restrictions on occasional  helping for free.  Unless perhaps you are "holding out"?

Comment: @MichaelHall The person said in his remark that it applied even if you're preaching for free. He did clarify that the laws could have changed. I don't know if I should edit my question or not. I'd like to know if any laws, whether the law requiring a work visa or otherwise, would prevent an American from simply preaching a free sermon north of the border every now and then.

Comment: The bounty's almost expired, and still no answer on this‽

Comment: Now that my bounty's ended, I'm supposed to award an answer. But there is no answer for me to award. 

Comment: This source distinguishes "work," which requires a work permit, and "volunteering," which does not, so maybe this source answers my question? https://www.canadavisa.com/charity-religious-work-visa.html#:~:text=The%20first%20distinction%20that%20must%20be%20made%20here,through%20the%20payment%20of%20regular%20and%20periodic%20wages.